# Send Arraydata from the from react to node. and save it in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I am trying to send an array from react using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to my Node.js file, however I am getting an status `404 error`.

My profileSchema as follows:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  },
  preference: [
    {
      type: String
    }
  ],

  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model("profile", ProfileSchema);
```

I want to send an array to the back end with an `axios request`.

for example

```
tempArray=["Chocoloate","Vanilla","Strawberry"]
```

and the axios request I make is

```
axios
    .post('/api/profile/register', tempArray)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

My `profile.js` look list this. I also have body-parse and all installed.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");

const Profile = require("../../models/Profile");
// Load User Model
const User = require("../../models/User");
router.get("/test", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "Profile Works" }));

// @route   POST api/profile
// @desc    Create or edit user profile
// @access  Private
router.post(
  "/register",

  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    var list = req.body;
    console.log(list);

  }
);
```

However, I am still getting 404 errors and not being able to save the array to the backend

index.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");

const users = require("./routes/api/users");
const profile = require("./routes/api/profile");
const posts = require("./routes/api/posts");
const issues = require("./routes/api/issues");
const mp = require("./routes/api/mp");

const app = express();

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(db)
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Passport Config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// Use Routes
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use('/api/profile', profile);
app.use("/api/posts", posts);
app.use("/api/issues", issues);
app.use("/api/mp", mp);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: please provide your `index.js` file of the backend, I mean, where you set up the whole API

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú added it.

Comment: please also provide your full implementation of the api/profile/register route

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú it is there in the profile.js part

Comment: are you hitting the right port with axios?

Comment: you said that `I am still getting 404 errors and not being able to save the array to the backend`, however, I didn't see the codes that you used to interact with the database :)

Comment: if you're working on your local QA env try axios
      .post('localhost:5000/api/profile/register', tempArray)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

Comment: Is your /test api works in profile.js?

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú I do not know how to save it to the array in the first place

Comment: Have you tried testing the end point in postman with dummy data localhost:5000/api/profile/register?  Where do you get 404 error is it in front end or backend?

Comment: @JayLane xhr.js:178 Failed to load localhost:5000/api/profile/register: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension . I get this error

Comment: @Think-Twice yes, it says  <pre>Cannot POST /api/profile/register</pre>

Comment: Doesnt the body for a POST API need to be an object?

Comment: @a2441918 can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Always try sending the post body as an object.

```js
tempArray = ['a', 'b', 'c']

axios
    .post('/api/profile/register', {tempArray: tempArray})
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

and the body params in the router.post as

```js
router.post('/register/', function(req, res,next) {

const tempArray = req.body.tempArray;

//perform your query operations here and pass tempArray as params to your query
})
```

Comment: Thanks, however I am still getting the error http://localhost:3000/api/profile/register 404 not found

Comment: Np, mark the answer as the correct one in case someone experiences the same issue as yours.